# Need to add column at the end of csv

Tags: shell-script, shell, csv

I need to add a column at the end of the csv
file *Interface_Utilization-95pctile_Report-en-us_2017-01-09T030009673Z.csv*.

```
Node_Name,Interface_Name,Interface_Speed,Utilization_In,Utilization_Out
```

Content of **Output.csv**

```
Node_Name,Interface_Name,Interface_Speed,Utilization_In,Utilization_Out,timestamp
```

The *timestamp* column should contain data from a variable stored in *$formatted_date*.

I've tried this so far:

```
ORIG_FILE="Interface_Utilization-95pctile_Report-en-us_2017-01-09T030009673Z.csv"
NEW_FILE="Output.csv"

awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$6="2012-02-29 16:13:00"; print}' \
  Interface_Utilization-95pctile_Report-en-us_2017-01-09T030009673Z.csv > Output.csv

awk '{ printf("%s,2012-02-29 16:13:00\n", $6); }' \
  Interface_Utilization-95pctile_Report-en-us_2017-01-09T030009673Z.csv > Output.csv

awk -F, -v OFS=, '{k=$3; $3="\"new text\"";}1' \
  Interface_Utilization-95pctile_Report-en-us_2017-01-09T030009673Z.csv

paste -d',' <(cut -d',' -f-2 file) \
  column.Interface_Utilization-95pctile_Report-en-us_2017-01-09T030009673Z.csv \
  <(cut -d',' -f3- file)
```

Comment: Please add real samples of your inpute/output CSV files

Comment: You have variables for `$formatted_date`, `$ORIG_FILE` and `$NEW_FILE`. I suggest you really use them ro you'll start over with your quoting when replacing the fixed strings by shell variables.

Answer (score 2):

So, actually you want to append a `,` and the double-quoted contents of `$formatted_date` to the end of every line? You can do this with

```
sed "s/$/,\"$formatted_date\"/" "$ORIG_FILE" > "$NEW_FILE"
```

Comment: There is any way, can I attached the output.csv, it is adding junk character in it

Comment: copy and paste part of the `input.csv` and matching part of the `output.csv` to your question. This works for what you told us, but maybe your file is different

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, including the header:

```
{ echo `head -1 $ORIG_FILE`",timestamp" ; tail -n +2 $ORIG_FILE | \
  while read x ; do echo "$x,$formatted_date" ; done ; } > $NEW_FILE
```

Comment: There is any way, can I attached the output.csv, it is adding junk character in it

Comment: @nvnvashisth, Re "_**it(1)** is adding junk ... in **it(2)**_":  Please specify which nouns each of the two "*it*" pronouns are being referred to.